# Azure Service bus queues have a URL, do they also have an IP-Adress or even Range?

Tags: azure, ip, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I was wondering if there is any possibility of Service Buses or even their queues have an IP-address or even Ranges? I have been searching both in the documentation and also in azure but I couldn't find anything.
What are the possibilities here when it comes to IP-Control so to speak? is it a question of upgrading the Pricing teir for the service bus?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work that way. The service is only accessible via DNS, not IP address.
Upgrading from Standard tier to Premium gives you throughput and latency commitment, but not an IP address.